# Ruby on Rails: Print element of array in a single line in html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, loops, erb

I'm new to html.erb files and I didn't find an answer to my problem.
I have array of names and I'm trying to print them in a paragraph tag `<p>` in one line with ',' like that:

```
name1, name2, name3
```

But instead I get this:

```
name1,
name2,
```

This is the code:

```
<% @names_array.each do |name| %>
  <p class="center"><%= name %>,</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: since you're new, you'd probably want to read up on html elements because your issue can be fixed in a lot of ways, eg using `span` instead of `p`, or changing the styling of `p` to `display:inline`.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp Also google for block vs inline html elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't something like this work?, just join them, leaving them inside the paragraph tag:

```
<p class="center">
  <%= @names_array.join(', ') %>
</p>
```

Comment: it worked but I have a ',' at the end like that: name1, name2, name3, and I don't want the last ',' how can I remove it through code?

Comment: @OfirSasson if the code above leaves an empty comma at the end, it means that your last name is either an empty string (`""`) or a `nil`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Active Support's `to_sentence` method. Example:

```
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']

irb(main):001:0> names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
=> ["name1", "name2", "name3"]

irb(main):002:0> names.to_sentence
=> "name1, name2 and name3"
```

You can modify the last connector passing a word option:

```
irb(main):003:0> names.to_sentence(last_word_connector: ', ')
=> "name1, name2, name3"
```

Check the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Conversions/to_sentence)